# UIImagePickerControllerのallowsEditing=YESにした時に背景透過のpngのリサイズの比率がおかしくなる

Tags: swift

UIImagePickerControllerのallowsEditing=YESにした時にクロップが出来ると思うのですが、背景透過のpngのリサイズをすると、画像の比率がおかしくなってしまいます。
[image: 元画像]

こちらの元画像を、下記のような感じでクロップします。

[image: 切り取りの範囲]

そうすると、背景が透過の部分がなくなってしまうためか、丸が潰れてimageviewに配置されてしまいます。
[image: リサイズ後]

UIImagePickerControllerで選択後には140x140pxのUIImageViewにセットしています。
上記のキャプチャでいう、黒い部分が140x140pxのUIImageViewです。

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.uiimageview.image = image
    println(image)
    println(editingInfo)
}
```

UIImageと、editingInfoのログは下記の通りでした。

```
<UIImage: 0x17409d100> size {1065, 1242} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
{
    UIImagePickerControllerCropRect = "NSRect: {{0, 6}, {243, 283}}";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x17409c660> size {244, 500} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=2AE8222F-5332-468D-BE25-5CE826E0ABEC&ext=PNG";
}
```

これを、比率を変更せずにUIImageViewに設置する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくクロップや背景透過とは関係無いと思います。

あらかじめ
`uiimageview.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit`
とセットしておくとどうでしょうか。

こうすることで、`UIImageView`の中にアスペクト比固定のまま最大のサイズで画像を表示することができます。